# What type of file does the new Heroku pg:backups public-url provide?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm working with [Heroku's new PGBackups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups) functionality and I have used the `public-url` command to [download a backup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#downloading-your-backups). The file isn't in a format that I'm used to. I was expecting a pg_dump file that I could open with Vim or another text editor. Does anyone know what the files that result from `public-url` are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pg_dump -Fc` ["custom" format](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html)

> c
>
> custom
>
> Output a custom-format archive suitable for input into pg_restore. Together with the directory output format, this is the most flexible output format in that it allows manual selection and reordering of archived items during restore. This format is also compressed by default.

Comment: Thanks. The compression is what threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

It sends you a file that you can use with the `pg_restore` command.

For example, I can download the file with:

```bash
curl -o /tmp/latest.dump <database_url>
```

And then restore with:

```bash
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d <destination_database_name> /tmp/latest.dump
```